# Sum function of a Matrix

Tags: r

For Matrix R

```
R[1,1] + R[5,1]
```

Gives me the proper number.

Where as

```
sum(R[1,1]:[5,1])
```

Does not. It gives me some value I do not recognize.

Say I have a Matrix:

```
     [,1]
[1,] 1
[2,] 7
[3,] 4
[4,] 4
[5,] 2
[6,] 5
```

In My mind:

```
 R[1,1] + R[5,1] = 3
```

and

```
sum(R[1,1]:R[5,1] = 18
```

Am I missing something.

Comment: Try `sum(R[1:5, 1])`. Otherwise `R[1,1]` returns 1 and `R[5,1]` returns `2` so you get `1:2` which is the vector `c(1,2)` and `sum(c(1,2))` is 3.

Comment: It adds up first to fifth values and return 18

Comment: Use `,` instead if `:` if you want to add only first and fifth valu and not intervening values